# Control email-adresses

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a public website created with Sharepoint 2007. In that I have a contact form where the client can leave a message ... I want that only clients who have a specific emailadress (only members of the company) can post a message. How can I control that using Active Directory or using some other solution ?

Comment: Is the site anonymous or not ?

Comment: What type of authentication you are using on the site FBA, Annoymous or AD based

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to replace the usual free text email address box with a custom textbox allowing only the internal name, anything after would be followed by @yourcompany.com if a single domain is matching with your reality.

If your site is anonymously available, you could create ad dedicated "contact" sub site that you'll restrict to only members of the company (thus not anonymously available). You could that way have your regular contact us form, only authenticated users will be able to fill in the form. (and will see the relevant sub site). You'll need to allow authentication on the public site to make it work (eg : have a sign in button with is linked to an available AD or FBA).